# Jquery Ajax Call does not Call the function in .CS file

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Always i get the alert in the "error". When i debugged i get the type,url as undefined. can anyone help me why that method is not getting called??

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnajaxcall").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/jQueryAjaxCalledMethod",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function () { alert('success') },
            error: function () { debugger; alert('failure'); return false; }
        });
    });
});   


[WebMethod]
public void jQueryAjaxCalledMethod()
{  
   //SOME CODE HERE       
}
```

Comment: why are you using webmethods...they're usually for non html based applications to gain access to the api provided by the webserver...u should be using controllers if you're using asp.net mvc

Comment: Hi Dave i have made that method static and yet i dont see it happening correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all i just used the jquery file hosted with google.

It worked out fine.

Previously i was using the jquery version 1.7.1 that i had downloaded and stored in my local. I also saw a lot of questions in the forum that this particular ajax call is quite not happening properly with .NET 4. I am not sure and forgive me if i am wrong but i do have a feeling that 1.7.1 in this case is not properly working with ASP.NET 4.

P.S -> I used this in the script tag --> 
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"

Comment: jQuery 1.7.1 doesn't have any ASP.Net references, if you creating the code correctly it should work, we use 1.7.1 with ajax calls and have not had any issues. **Edit** Just realised this was your question, you might have errors with your code, moving back to 1.4.2 seems like a temp solution to me

Comment: Hi Skuld. My code is absolutely fine and i am pretty confident about it.

Answer (score 2):

If im correct you should be using static method for these purposes, so function in your code behind should look like this

```
[WebMethod]
public static void jQueryAjaxCalledMethod()
{  
   //SOME CODE HERE       
}
```

If you still get some errors take a look on this guy blog [Encosia](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) maybe you'll find there a solution

Comment: Hi Ale_lipa. I tried it making the method static and rechecking all the attributes in the Ajax call. Still the control never hits the jQueryAjaxCalledMethod function that is defined in the code. I m a lil baffled !

Comment: Try to put entire URL path in the ajax url property, like `http://your_page_address.com/Default.aspx/jQueryAjaxCalledMethod`. In the future check out some programmers tools (eg. Firebug in Firefox, Fiddler2 etc.) where you can view the requests and responses and really easy debug the problem

Comment: Hi Ale_lipa yes i did that too... i read the blog that u had given and copied the same code that he had given but in vain. i m using jquery-1.7.1 library. is it something to do with library?

Comment: Hi Ale_lipa is it ok if i mailed u my whole sample code?? Can you please check this thing if u have time!??

Comment: The library has probably nothing to do with it. Sending me your code is pointless. Better try to focus on tools that i've sugested to use and track issue. For instanse, if you've got Chrome browser hit f12 on your website than go to network tab. Now (keep the tool opened) perform some click event on your page that you've bindend your ajax call and observe your request in opened window. Check everything you can (eg. Request URL if it's correct), response etc.

Comment: FYI: The issue with using static page-methods over that of HttpHandlers is you will (always) incurr the overhead associated with the page-life-cycle.

Comment: Hi all i just used the jquery file hosted with google. It worked out fine. I used the jquery version 1.7.1 stored in local. <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

The jquery Ajax method is going to post your data in json format using the plain html protocol. ASP.NET will be expecting to unwrap a SOAP request to pass to the webmethod. Thus the error. You should use an MVC action instead, as suggested in one of the comments.
EDIT:On further investigation ASP.Net has an attribute that will allow the web method to be called:
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]. 
Use this attribute on the class and it might solve your problem.