# Can't save data in database with Json in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I want to save my data in database with json. I'm using following code, neither it giving me any error nor it able to save data in database. Please help me. I'm new to json.

```
function myfun() {
        var name = $('[id$=txt1]').val();
        var email = $('[id$=txt2]').val();
        var address = $('[id$=txt3]').val();
        var salary = $('[id$=txt4]').val();
        var data = { name: name, email: email, address: address, salary: salary };
        alert(data.val());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/save",
            // data: "{'name':'" + name + "','email':'" + email + "','address':'" + address + "','salary':'" + salary + "'}",
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
                $('[id$=lbl1]').val(data.d)
            },
            error: function(msg) {
                alert("failed: " + msg);
            }

        });

    }
```

---------------Server side code--------------------

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public String save(String name, String email, String address, Int32 salary)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText="insert tbfirst values(@name, @email, @address, @salary)";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name",System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = email;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@address", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = address;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@salary", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = salary;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
        return "Success";


    }
```

Comment: Have you debug your server code to check that ajax call is received? put he break point on your method and attach the iis process to debug..

Comment: I don't find any problems in jQuery code. Have you tried setting a break-point in save() function ? If its not getting called then make your function **Static** and then try.

Comment: @Talha, yes i have checked this, i put brea point on my mwthod, but its not getting call by jason...

Answer (score 1):

Please try to stringify you data:

```
$.ajax({ 
....,
data: JSON.stringify(data),
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely unrelated to the ajax request but instead related to the line just above

```
var data = { name: name, email: email, address: address, salary: salary };
alert(data.val());
```

since the data object does not have a `val` method the line with the alert should fail. If you look in the debug console of your browser I'd be surprised if there's not an error message saying something like "TypeError: Object # has no method 'val'"

Answer (score 0):

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static String save(String name, String email, String address, Int32 salary)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText="insert tbfirst values(@name, @email, @address, @salary)";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name",System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = email;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@address", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = address;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@salary", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = salary;

```
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Dispose();
    return "Success";


}
```

you only use public string, user public static string

Answer (score -1):

If you're using ASP.NET (not MVC) you'll have to use this *save* WebMethod as a static one. I've wrote similar answer in this thread [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890554/jquery-ajax-call-does-not-call-the-function-in-cs-file/8891033#8891033). Check the link that've provided in this answer it's really helpfull.

Also you should start using tools like Firebug (in Firefox) or some other WebDeveloper Tools that specific browser is providing. It's very usefull to inspect your requests and response.

Comment: read with understanding..I'm aware that he is using WebMethod but the method isn't **STATIC** and that could be the case