# ASP.NET Custom Validator + WebMethod + jQuery + .Net 4 + does not work

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, customvalidator

my situation is like this thread :
[ASP.NET Custom Validator + WebMethod + jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982420/asp-net-custom-validator-webmethod-jquery)
my aspx codes :

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox" runat="server" Width="170px" ValidationGroup="A" CssClass="txt"
            TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvPass" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="TextBox"
            ValidationGroup="A" ClientValidationFunction="CheckPass">
            invalid
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

jquery:

```
    function CheckPass(source, args) {
        alert('asd');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            timeout: 500,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "Default.aspx/CheckPassword",
            data: '{"Value":"' + args.Value + '"}',
            success: function (result) {
                alert('a');
                args.IsValid = result.d;
            }
        });
    }
```

code behind (c#):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Telerik.Web.UI;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace Nasim
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod]
        public static bool CheckPassword(string pass)
        {
             return false;
        }
    }
}
```

as you see i want to check password using custom validator in ajax mode(using jquery).
but i do n't know why $.ajax does not work for me at all.
there is no error and nothing happens and always have postback.
should i add an specific library other that jquery?
i am using visual studio 2010 + .Net 4.
what is the problem and how can i fix it?

thanks in advance

Comment: Does the `alert` fire?  Are you including any other javascript libraries besides jquery?  Have you looked at the response of the post in a tool like firebug?

Comment: i did n't see alert('a');  at all. working on firebug!

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the `alert('asd')` when I said alert.  Just was confirming that your js function was actually getting called.

Comment: there is no problem about alert('asd'); mean if fires. please see this thread -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890554/jquery-ajax-call-does-not-call-the-function-in-cs-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the code you've showed it should work but there are potentially some other areas of your code that could be contributing to your problems.

Some areas I'd investigate:

- You're using a validation group for your text box and custom validator. Does the control that triggers postback also include the ValidationGroup="A" attribute?
- When calling the Web Method you're passing in `'{"Value":"' + args.Value + '"}',` as your data to the method call. I think you need to change `"Value"` to `"pass"` to match the Web Method parameter name.
- I haven't worked much with Telerik controls. Perhaps the `RadScriptManager` is intercepting events in some way?

I'd recommend creating a version of your page that just uses the bare minimum of code to prove whether what you're trying to do works or not: a simple page, with a text box control, the custom validator, the jQuery code and the web method in the code behind.

Hopefully that will help you uncover any problems.

Comment: really thanks for nice attention. solved-> "Value" to "pass". so there is no problem about RadScriptManager. also the control that triggers postback has ValidationGroup="A".